# Fatal error</b>: Call to a member function withJson() on array in

Tags: php, slim

i am new to PHP coding and am trying to set up with Slim 3. I am just trying to write an add function to add **fname, lname, address, email & age.**
 I keep getting the error:

> **"Fatal error:  Call to a member function withJson() on array in"**

this is for the line:

```
"return $res->withJson(["person"=>$data],404)->withAddedHeader('Location',"/users/$id", ["text"=>"person does not exist"]);" after the "catch(PDOException $e) {".
```

Thanks in advance..

Here is the code:

```
<?php
/POST /persons : add a new person
$app->post('/persons', function ($req, $res){
    try{
// check if all data is there
    $data=$req->getParsedBody();


    $filter = [
         'fname' => [
            'filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,
            'options' => [
               'regexp' => '/[a-zA-Z]+/'
            ]
         ],
         'lname' => [
            'filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,
            'options' => [
            'regexp' => '/[a-zA-Z]+/'
            ]
         ],
         'address' => [
            'filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,
            'options' => [
            'regexp' => '/[a-zA-Z]+/'
            ]
         ],
         'email' => [
            'filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL,
            'options' => [
            'regexp' =>'/[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+/'
            ]
         ],
         'age' => [
         'filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
         'options' => [
         'regexp' => '/{1,100}'
         ]
         ]
    ];

    $res = filter_var_array($data,$filter);

    if(empty($data)){
        return $res->withJson( ["error"=>
                                      [ "text" => "The information provided is inadequate"]
                                      ],400);
        }else 
// ....
$sql = 'insert into person (fname, lname, address, email, age)values(:fname,:lname,:address,:email,:age)';
// prepare
$stmt =$this->db->prepare($sql);
// execute with values from $data

$stmt->execute(['fname'=>$res['fname'],'lname'=>$res['lname'],'address'=>$res['address'],'email'=>$res['email'],'age'=>$res['age']]);
// take lastinsertid and make a new header Location with it
$id = $this->db->lastInsertId();
// return a JSON saying all ok and new location

return $res->withJson(["person"=>$data],201)->withAddedHeader('Location',"/users/$id", ["text"=>"person added correctly"]);

}
 catch(PDOException $e) {
 return $res->withJson(["person"=>$data],404)->withAddedHeader('Location',"/users/$id", ["text"=>"person does not exist"]);

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$res = filter_var_array($data,$filter);` returns you array. The array type does not have method `withJson()`. This is the problem. Probably, you want to use `json_encode()` function.

---

Ok then do 2 things:

#1. change:

```
$res = filter_var_array($data,$filter);
```

to

```
$params = filter_var_array($data,$filter);
```

#2. change:

```
$stmt->execute(['fname'=>$res['fname'],'lname'=>$res['lname'],'address'=>$res['address'],'email'=>$res['email'],'age'=>$res['age']]);
```

to

```
$stmt->execute([
    'fname' => $params['fname'],
    'lname' => $params['lname'],
    'address' => $params['address'],
    'email' => $params['email'],
    'age' => $params['age']
]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! When i use json_encode() i print out the array but it says fname = null. Also it is not posting to the database.

Comment: You're just using the same variable for filtered input data and response object, please take a look at update in answer's body.